# Error on Play application startup

Tags: linux, playframework

I have noticed non-blocking (seemingly) error in my Play application log.
It happens on startup after deploy. I do not see any negative effects but still that log entry is warrying. Here goes a part of the stacktrace:

```
2015-03-23 22:34:48,753 - [INFO] - from play in main 
database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bowlingdb?characterEncoding=UTF-8

2015-03-23 22:34:48,851 - [ERROR] - from net.sf.ehcache.Cache in main 
Unable to set localhost. This prevents creation of a GUID. Cause was: ip-172-30-0-197: ip-172-30-0-197: Name or service not known
java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-172-30-0-197: ip-172-30-0-197: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
        at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.<clinit>(Cache.java:214) ~[net.sf.ehcache.ehcache-core-2.6.8.jar:na]
        at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createCache(ConfigurationHelper.java:296) [net.sf.ehcache.ehcache-core-2.6.8.jar:na]
```

Could you help me to figure out why this happens?
App is hosted on Amazon EC2 Linux instance.

Comment: What's in your /etc/hosts?

Comment: Hi @Ryan
This is what I have there: `127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain`

Comment: The problem might be that your hostname appears to be `ip-172-30-0-197` but that isn't mapped in your /etc/hosts.  Add that hostname and see if it works.

Comment: But what is the source of this problem? I see that error is thrown by some cache. I do not use mem-cache explicitly....

Comment: Your error suggests that ehCache is trying to start but isn't able to bind to your hostname.  This often happens when your hostname isn't mapped in /etc/hosts.

Comment: adding `172.30.0.197   ip-172-30-0-197 localhost' line resolved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ryan suggested problem was that host name of my linux box was not mapped in the etc/hosts.
Question resolved.